# How to enable high compliancy mode in babeljs

Tags: node.js, babeljs

On babeljs website, there is [interactive transpiler/interpreter](https://babeljs.io/repl/) that enables so called "high compliancy" option, making transpiler a little bit more strict.

However using babeljs in my nodejs project, I was not able to find option or flag that enables this mode. I did not find it in [options documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) Where is it?

I use es2015 preset in my nodejs project, if it helps.